# imap_search not working with ks_c_5601-1987 in php

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to search subject of mail with imap_search() but it doesn't work on ks_c_5601-1987 encoded subject.
It works well on utf-8 encoded subject.

```
imap_search($imap, 'SUBJECT mail_subject_test', SE_FREE); 
or
imap_search($imap, 'SUBJECT mail_subject_test', SE_FREE, "UTF-8");
```

it works at

```
["subject"]=>
  string(97) "=?utf-8?B?7J247YS07IKs7JuQIOyhsOyXsOyjvCDsnbzsnbzsl4XrrLTsnbzsp4DsnoXri4g=?= =?utf-8?B?64ukLg==?="
```

but it doesn't work at

```
["subject"]=>
  string(69) "=?ks_c_5601-1987?B?wM7Fz7vnv/ggwNO9w8H4IMDPwM++97mrwM/B9sDUtM+02S4=?="
```

Does the function imap_search() not work on ks_c_5601-1987? or are there any good solution?

Thank in advance.

Comment: It depends on the server software.  The server needs to implement support for every charset you're interested in, because searching is done server side, and it needs to decode messages to match.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Max. Then what can I do now? Can I modify the server configuration to implement support for every charset?

Comment: You'd have to look up the documentation for your server software.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for some. Have a good day :)